# When should I use the Samsung SDK for developing an Android app?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

When should we prefer to develop an Android application using the Samsung SDKs instead of using the Android SDK? What are the basic advantages of using the Samsung SDK? Could the application developed using the Samsung SDK run on a non-Samsung Android 
device? Is there a way to test the application developed using the Android SDK on Samsung emulators?

Are there any advantages such as performance, animation, if we use the `Samsung SDK` to target only 
Samsung devices?

I am now targeting `Samsung Tab` only, I am wondering how much difficulties it will be if i have to migrate the application to support all `Android devices` in future?

Comment: Presumably *only* if you use Samsung-unique functionality not supported by the Android SDK or simply by adding a library.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say ... never ! unless you develop specific apps for the Samsung Stylus or something like that. As @Amadas points, if you use Samsung SDK, you have all the odds that your application won't work on any Android device that is not manufactured by Samsung. Why would you want that? On the other hand, if you use the standard Android SDK, your stuff will work on Samsungs, and in the rest of devices.

Comment: Samsung SDK is really bad. Its quality is really low, and for all support questions they bounce it to google. Stay away from Samsung SDK.

Comment: absolutely! I can't agree more with you. They are the champions of bloatware.

Comment: @rupps can i use it for text handwriting but for another device?? not just samsung?? i am kinda confused since some docs mention tht it only requires samsung devices and some mention any.

Comment: @Raratouille, the text handwriting recognition is a proprietary Samsung SDK (S-Pen) : http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/handwriting-recognition/201/248977?boardName=SDK&startId=zzzzz~ ... You have to download such SDK from Samsung and integrate it into your App. It won't work on devices without an S-Pen (galaxy note) . What you can do is use the feature IF the device is a Samsung -you will detect this- but you should provide an alternate input method for the rest of the world to not rule out a big % of the Android ecosystem from running your app beforehand !

Comment: Even their own SDK and device hardware they do not support. So be careful before deciding to do anything with Samsung SDK. I have used it recently and had HORRID experiences. They will use excuses like "cannot reproduce", "visit the nearest samsung store for a update", "does the phone have any physical damage", and then finally "its a android issue". Really lame!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make an application for a non-Samsung Android device, don't use the Samsung SDK. The Samsung SDK contains special methods for Samsung Android devices. Some functions are the same, but function names and/or functionality can be different, so I recommend using the Android SDK.